# Convert .OFF files to .OBJ in Python

Tags: python, object, format

I downloaded [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/balraj98/modelnet40-princeton-3d-object-dataset?resource=download) dataset that provides many CAD models, in the **.off** format.
I want to import these models in Blender, but apparently there is no support for this format.

So I was looking for a python script to convert .off files to .obj, but I didn't find anything.
What can I do?